# Tire - Elasticsearch - how to skip indexing on create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I' m working on a rails app. using gem tire as a bond for elasticsearch.
in a multistep form I would like to index at the end of the procedure.

is there a way of skipping indexing on create.

guess: Post.create( :indexing => false ) or whatever

or in tire config say : only index Post with attribute :published set to true

Hope I made myself clear. thanks in advance for your answers.

Cheers.

Comment: ok i guess I found out myself... don'tf look at the timestamps please...

In the indexed model you can add:

after_save do
   update_index if published == true
end

Hope it'll help some future lazy folks

ok i guess I found out myself... don'tf look at the timestamps please...

In the indexed model you can add:

after_save do
   update_index if published == true
end

Hope it'll help some future lazy folks

Comment: Do not "include Tire::Model::Callbacks" in your model if you use this method (cf. https://github.com/karmi/tire/issues/486).

Comment: @Stan - be sure to write up an answer and mark it as accepted.  Nothing wrong with answering your own question!

Answer (score 0):

re: your answer above, after_save is called on create too so a better, more general answer to your question (i think) would be to make sure not to include Tire::Model::Callbacks in your model then

```
after_create :my_callback

def my_callback
  false
end
```

Comment: just be careful here because after_save fires on create too, so if you're using that you'll have to figure out a way to make sure it doesn't fire on create as well.